# “Secular” approximation in the Lindblad equation for an open quantum system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information, open-quantum-systems

**Some context**: I am deriving the Lindblad equation following “The Theory of Open Quantum Systems” by Breuer and Petruccione (somebody transcribed the section I am reading in [this link](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Open_Quantum_Systems/The_Quantum_Optical_Master_Equation)).

**My question**: I am stuck understanding the so-called “secular approximation”, i.e. neglecting the “rapidly oscillating” terms with $\omega' \neq \omega$ in
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \rho_s(t) = \sum_{\alpha, \beta} \sum_{\omega’,\omega} e^{i t (\omega’ -\omega)} \Gamma_{\alpha \beta}(\omega)\left(A_{\beta}(\omega)\rho_s(t) A^{\dagger}_{\alpha} (\omega’)-A^{\dagger}_{\alpha}(\omega’) A_{\beta}(\omega) \rho_s(t)\right) + h.c.
$$
so that it becomes
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \rho_s(t) = \sum_{\alpha, \beta} \sum_{\omega} \Gamma_{\alpha \beta}(\omega)\left(A_{\beta}(\omega)\rho_s(t) A^{\dagger}_{\alpha} (\omega)-A^{\dagger}_{\alpha}(\omega) A_{\beta}(\omega) \rho_s(t)\right) + h.c. \quad .
$$
I am new to the field of open quantum systems so I missed Breuer and Petruccione’s arguments of relaxation times being small and terms being rapidly oscillating.

Comment: You may want to consider a simpler case first, as in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/556440/49107).

Comment: @Anyon , thanks for the link! Following the gist of that post, the argument would be that $$ \rho_s(t) = \sum_{\alpha, \beta} \sum_{\omega’,\omega} \Gamma_{\alpha \beta}(\omega)\left(A_{\beta}(\omega)\int dt e^{i t (\omega’ -\omega)} \rho_s(t) A^{\dagger}_{\alpha} (\omega’)-A^{\dagger}_{\alpha}(\omega’) A_{\beta}(\omega) \int dt e^{i t (\omega’ -\omega)} \rho_s(t)\right) + h.c.,$$ integrals like $$\int dt e^{i t (\omega’ -\omega)} \rho_s(t)$$ are much smaller when $\omega’ \neq \omega$ than when $\omega’ = \omega$ **provided** (?) $\rho_s(t)$ is slow changing in comparison to the exponentials.